# Can I control my shower temperature and pressure independently?

Tags: plumbing, shower

In my shower, I currently have the following setup:

[image]

However, the problem with this setup is that I can't control the temperature and the pressure of the water independently. That is, as soon as I start rotating the knob clockwise, the temperature of the water starts out cold, and its pressure is low. The more I keep turning, the higher the temperature **and** the pressure of the water. I want to be able to have cold water with high pressure and hot water with low pressure. I am thinking of installing something like the setup shown in the image below, where I can turn the lever left and right to control temperature, and up and down to control pressure. The pipe shown in the image below is connected directly to the shower head, while in my current setup in the image above, the water goes to the shower head from the wall. However, I wanted to know if it is even possible to replace the setup I already have above with the one below so that I can control temperature and pressure independently.

[image]

Comment: I feel your pain - I am also very much _not_ a fan of these single function faucets. Are you sure that you cannot find a single-hole shower faucet that gives you separate control of temperature and flow? That would be, by far, the easiest solution. You might try visiting a dedicated plumbing supply store instead of your local big-box home improvement place.

Comment: @FreeMan do these single-hole shower faucets exist?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something wrong with your valve?  IME those valves operate at one water pressure (OK, maybe the first tiny bit of travel through "cold" is lower flow).  Are you trying to get high pressure cold water or something?

Comment: My shower faucet has a rotating handle for volume and a concentric rotating knob for temperature. The escutcheon is almost identical to what you have. Do you have access from the rear (even if through drywall)?

Comment: @Huesmann yes, I’m trying to get hot water at low pressure and cold water at high pressure.

Comment: @isherwood yes, I have access to the pipes behind the faucet inside the wall. Would the concentric faucet that you’re describing help in this case?

Comment: @mhdadk it would be a bit of a hack, but the mix on those knobs is adjustable internally.  You could adjust the knob so that the hot comes on later, which would give you the higher pressure cold.  Then use an inline valve at the shower head (see example in my reply to the 1st answer) to cut down the pressure on full hot water.

Comment: Sure seems like it. Hit up your favorite home improvement store and pick out a valve with a similar design and go to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace your current valve with the type in the bottom picture, would require a lot of work on your shower wall. Cutting new holes, covering old ones.

You can try contacting a plumbing supply company to find a valve that fits behind the current opening you have  and performs separate temperature and volume functions. (they used to be common, but are harder to find now)

Another option would be to add a volume control between your mixing valve and shower head. One small new hole will have to be made in the shower.

Any work will need access behind the shower wall to change valves or add one.

Comment: “You can try contacting a plumbing supply company to find a valve that fits behind the current opening you have and performs separate temperature and volume functions.” Would you possibly have a link to one of these? I’m not sure what these would be called or look like.

Comment: @mhdadk I've seen two models: the ones which look just as in the question, except you push/pull to control flow (very difficult to fine tune flow but it is possible), and the ones which have a large handle you pull up/down to turn on/off and turn sideways for temperature, exactly like many kitchen faucets work. Looks can be misleading so it's best to try a demo in store to make sure there is independant control.

Comment: Trying to find the best valve for you may be a "needle in the haystack" on the internet.  The best bet is to contact a plumbing supply and tell them what your goal is. They will give you your options with pricing.

Comment: The easy button is to add a valve inline with the shower head, like this: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rrddPuPJL._AC_.jpg

Comment: "(they used to be common, but are harder to find now)" Is this some other country than the US? Because separate temperature and volume are quite common here.

Comment: "replacing would require a lot of work" - not in my last 2 houses. The Victorians thoughtfully provided a tasteful cabinet door in the wall. Open the door and you're staring at the backside of the tub faucet. I certainly think anyone who has to cut drywall to get to a tub faucet should fit a cabinet door there - upside: no mud or whole-wall-repaint required, just paint it trim color.

Comment: For something like this, a good plumbing supply store - as opposed to one of the big box/have everything stores - is a better place to go.

Answer (score 4):

There are several different arrangements of "1-handle" tub faucets.

Some of them, typically in hotels, give exactly the action you say: you turn it to both turn it on and adjust temperature and there is no flow adjustment.  Others look exactly like yours, but you *pull them out* for flow and *turn them* for temperature.  Yet others look like yours, but you pivot them (pitch) upward for flow and rotate for temp.

I would search your valve's action carefully for any "second dimension of movement".

Otherwise I would replace with a tub faucet you like.

It is important that the tub faucet be a "1-handle" and have a thermostatic protection (anti-scald).  That is the whole reason tub faucets went to 1-handle.  That allows you to crank up the water heater to 140°F/60°C, which has two desirable effects: #1 it prevents the heater from breeding dangerous bacteria.  And #2 it means longer showers, since you're mixing *less* hot with *more* cold.

The reason people in the past typically kept heaters at 120°F/50°C is fear of scalding.  Scalding is a risk with old school non-thermostatic valves, typically 2-handle.  However this creates a perfect breeding ground for legionella and other bacteria.  If you're wondering why this is news to you, it's news to *everyone* - remember how Flint, Michigan changed their water supply?  The sudden change caused an explosion of cases all at once, allowing it to be identified. They then realized that cases like this had been happening everywhere all along, just dribbling in slowly so the pattern was not detected.

Comment: The one-control valves of that type which I have seen give intermediate levels of pressure by pulling the knob out only partway rather than fully.